# Match rows of a dataframe based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with activities of different units and the starting and ending dates of these activities. I need to know whether there are units that have started a new activity within 31 days after ending one and what these activities were (their ID).

I have tried to use the `dplyr` package: specifically I used `group_by(unit)` and then `summarise, but I cannot see how I get the answer.

```r
# Dataframe
unit <- rep(LETTERS[1:4], c(2,2,3,3))
start <- as.Date(c("2017-02-28", "2018-03-26", "2017-08-01", "2018-01-23", "2016-08-29", "2016-12-12", "2017-04-12", "2016-11-01", "2016-11-08", "2017-04-03"))
end <- as.Date(c("2018-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2018-10-23", "2017-03-31", "2017-12-31", "2019-02-28", "2017-03-31", "2017-03-31", "2018-08-31"))

DF <- data.frame(unit, start, end)
> DF
   unit      start        end
1     A 2017-02-28 2018-12-31
2     A 2018-03-26 2018-12-31
3     B 2017-08-01 2017-12-31
4     B 2018-01-23 2018-10-23
5     C 2016-08-29 2017-03-31
6     C 2016-12-12 2017-12-31
7     C 2017-04-12 2019-02-28
8     D 2016-11-01 2017-03-31
9     D 2016-11-08 2017-03-31
10    D 2017-04-03 2018-08-31
```

The output I would like to get would be a dataframe like this:

```
   unit      activity1        activity2
1     B              3               4
2     C              5               7
3     D              8              10
4     D              9              10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simone!

In your example e.g. activity 4 actually starts less than 31 days after actvity 6 ended but  it is not listed in your desired result - I guess because these activities belong to different units.

Thus, I assume that you want to get your results per unit. You could do it like this:

```
DF$no <- 1:nrow(DF)
spl <- split[DF, DF$unit]
output <- do.call(rbind, 
        lapply(split(DF, DF$unit), function(x){
          unit.activities <- c()
          for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
            delta_end <- difftime(x$start[i], x$end)
            ended_last_month <- which(delta_end>=0 & delta_end<=31)
            if (length(ended_last_month)>0) {
              return(do.call(rbind, lapply(ended_last_month, function(j){c(as.character(x$unit[i]), x$no[j], x$no[i])})))
            }
          }
          return(as.data.frame(unit.activities))
        })
        )
names(output) <- c('unit', 'activity1', 'activity2')
rownames(output) <- 1:nrow(output)

> output
  unit activity1 activity2
1    B         3         4
2    C         5         7
3    D         8        10
4    D         9        10
```